# Contribution Error: "failed to update contribution in database"

Tags: civicontribute, stripe

UPDATE. I'm not posting this as an answer since it provides none. When 5.34 became available, I tried an update on this site and the problem went away. I guess there was an issue with 5.33.2. I'll likely never know.

Weird situation. I have just upgraded to CiviCRM 5.33.2 and Stripe 6.5.6 on Wordpress 5.6.

When I test a Contribution after the upgrade, I get an on screen error saying "Failed to update contribution in database".

I reviewed the logs for clues and found nothing very useful. The Apache error log is clean and the Civi log (even with debugging on) reports only

`Jan 21 14:59:56  [info] Contribution record updated successfully`

Reviewing Stripe directly shows a successful (test) payment and CiviCRM shows the same.

I have tested a single live payment just to see if there is any difference. It behaves the same way as the test payments (as it should).

The only additional clue I am receiving is that no email is received either. However, testing the outbound SMTP settings returns success and the test email is received.

Any thoughts on where to look for clues?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer since it provides none. When 5.34 became available, I tried an update on this site and the problem went away. I guess there was an issue with 5.33.2. I'll likely never know.